# "Update to Recommended Settings" Xcode 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode7, bundle-identifier, build-settings

I am a little late to the Xcode 7 update, but I did it just this morning and am noticing this 'Update to recommended settings' warning displayed by Xcode. I have done some research and haven't found much other than users posting about this same warning with older releases of Xcode. This leads me to believe Apple will occasionally suggest changes in settings after big updates (I only have about 1.5 years Xcode experience).

In any case, it appears the warning just wants to change my bundle identifier. How cautious should I be before performing the changes?

[image: Update to Recommended Settings]

Comment: check the following http://www.stevetrefethen.com/blog/upgrading-an-ios-project-from-xcode-6-to-7

Comment: You always should use version control systems ( like Git ). With VCS you can do any experiments you want without a risk to lose something.

Comment: I also get those messages for projects for which I have not yet registered an App ID in the Developer Center.  The project is at a point where I'm just testing out code for the feasibility of continuing on to a real app. If you haven't associated a valid App ID with the project, the bundle ID used to default to your Apple ID plus whatever you've set for PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER.  Now it seems Apple (and Xcode) want to do it explicitly. As for me, I just ignore the messages until I actually do get a valid App ID for the project.